# Android adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() not working?

Tags: android

I'm writing an app that requires getting input from the user, passing it off to a server, which returns a JSON string, and then displaying its parsed contents in a ListView. I'm currently accomplishing this by extending AsyncTask:

```
//stripped down version
public class main extends ListActivity {

ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
final EditText input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);


input.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {    
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {   
            if(!input.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            new GetDataTask().execute(input.getText().toString());
        }

    }   
});

private class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... query) {

        URL url = new URL("http://myserversaddressgoeshere.com/search/thequerygoeshere");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
        //the code that parses the JSON goes here; it writes some strings to items
        return items;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> items) {
            listItems = items;
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
}

}
```

(This is my first post so I apologize in advance if my attempt to make that a code block fails)

In the onPostExecute method, after setting listItems equal to items, if I print the contents of listItems, they're exactly what I want. But, for some reason, when executed from onPostExecute, adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() seems to do nothing (when it's called from the main thread, it works fine).

If anyone has any idea of what's going on and/or how to fix it, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

can you try this

```
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> items) {
        listItems.clear();
        listItems.addAll(items);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

and i do hope you are already doing something this

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(listItems);
```

Comment: whoops, I left that declaration out. 

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);

Comment: And that worked; Thank you very much! Out of curiosity, do you know why clear -> addAll -> notifyDSC works but what I had doesn't?

Comment: When you declare the arrayadapter you passed the **reference/pointer** of listItems and in __onPostExecute__ you were expected to update the values to the reference. **litsItems=items just assigns a new reference/pointer to the variable __listItems__**. i know my comment is confusing but its really simple concept.

Comment: So it's passing the reference instead of the object; that makes sense. Thanks!